# Управление пакетами npm развернутыми глобально

Tags: node.js, npm

Устанавливал на windows10 node.js с [офсайта](https://nodejs.org/en/), вместе с ней шёл npm в комплекте.

> ```
> C:\temp>node -v
> v8.12.0
>
> C:\temp>npm -v
> 6.4.1
> ```

Места на SSD уже не хватает — вот, хочу теперь почистить глобально установленные пакеты и заново поустанавливать только те, которые требуются в работе.

Как это лучше сделать? Есть какая-то папка для кеша, которую можно просто грохнуть или есть какие-то специфические команды?

Comment: Пардон, а разве [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) так плохо документирован?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотреть настройки npm можно дав команду `npm config ls -l`

Собственно, настроек две:

```
prefix = "C:\\Users\\ak\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
cache = "C:\\Users\\ak\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache"
```

Альтернативно посмотреть можно через `npm list -g --depth=0`

Смотрел содержимое этих папок на чистой виртуалке, пробовал чистить:

- очистка глобальных пакетов C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
- очистка кеша C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\

Comment: Ну или очищать аккуратно по одному через `npm uninstall -g packagename`

Comment: А разве `npm cache clean` не очищает кэш? (Сам я не проверял за ненадобностью)

Comment: Вернее, `npm cache clean --force`.

Comment: @Yaant Кстати да. После запуска остаётся одна пустая папка и какой-то служабный файл, но работает. Правда, глобальные не удаляет.